# what is the difference between sizing an image via image.width/height vs image.style.height/width

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a large png image (15000x6000) that I load into chrome.  I use the image for data analysis (convolutions etc).

I created a smaller version for viewing (coffeescript) via CSS style:

```
img.setAttribute 'style',
"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:#{w};height:#{h};z-index:#{z}"
```

where w, h are the width/height of the smaller image (z is used to create an ordered stack of elements)

This works, but seems to actually reduce the original image size too, rather than simply scaling the page display size!  I.e. when I look at the original image width, it is reduced.

I get around this by creating a second, clone image of the original.  I do this by setting the clone width/height to the smaller value, and then setting the img.src to the original src.  This seems to work.

Is this the expected behavior?  Do "thumbnails" and other image stunts actually decrease the initial image size?  Profiling doesn't help .. chrome has removed its Native Memory functionality, sigh.

Comment: What you mean by "look at the original image width, it is reduced"?  How exactly are you looking at it, and what in particular do you mean by "original"?

Comment: [This demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uyIQaRo/1) has an 800x1200 image in an `<img>` tag whose style is set to display at 200x300.  If you right-click the image and view its "info", the size is still reported as 800x1200.  The browser doesn't throw pixels away.

Comment: The question in your title is not alluded to in the question body, was that intentional? The answer is that just `width` is the width attribute, which can only take a number in pixels, while `style.width` is the style property, which requires a unit (i.e. the suffix `px`). And you can set them both, but then the style overrides the attribute.

Comment: Pointy: original: made via new Image(); reduced: via the image shown in HTML with reduced size.  Your demo answered the question tho .. hovering over the <img..> shows 200x300 pixels (Natural: 800x1200). Puzzled, I found naturalWidth/Height which were sure enough the original values.  The browser hadn't cropped after all and the original image could be used for further data analysis.  Whew!

Comment: Pointy: how do I mark your comment as the correct answer?